# SIlverlight and WCF RIA

Tags: silverlight, wcf, ria, code-reuse

I have an application where I present the data to the users by using Silverlight 4 and WCF RIA Services. In this application I have also a module (console app) which is responsible to store in the DB some flat files (xml files).

My question is: According to the best practices which one of these two options is the best?

1. Reuse the WCF RIA Services also for the Console App to store the flat files in DB.
2. Create others WCF Services specific for the Console App to store the flat files in DB (with ServiceContract).

Any idea? Or other options?
THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

All I can say is it is always a best practice to **`reuse any code that can be reused`**. I don't see why you would want to create a whole new service layer for another application? Being reusable (over multiple applications/platforms) is the point of web services.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback... But what about bulk processing? I need to store the csv files in the DB, is WCF RIA supporting this? THANKS